# TFS clone build link other branch

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I use VS2010 builds. I create build containing multiple solution and custom properties (custom template).
When I clone a build definition, like it should, it keep all path to the "branch" of the build. So if I want to create a build for a new branch, it could be long because I need to change like 20 path/properties. Is there a way to create a button that create a build, based on existant build but with properties based on another branch? Maybe there's a way to edit the build definition xml file after cloning it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible for you to do these adjustments automatically, you have to do it manually.